# Est-ce qu'en français il existe des pronoms anciens ou spéciaux?

Tags: pronoms, histoire, oral

Dans ma langue maternelle, l'espagnol, il y a certains pronoms très anciens ou qui ont une utilisation particulière, qu'on trouve seulement dans quelques textes anciens comme la Bible, dans des romans, ou qui sont utilisés dans des régions spécifiques. Ces pronoms sont ***vos*** et ***vosotros***, le premier est très utilisé en Argentine, et le second en Espagne, mais ils ne sont pas généralisés à d'autres lieux, ou existent seulement dans des textes narratifs. Le même cas existe en anglais avec les pronoms ***thou*** et ***ye*** mais, à la différence de l'espagnol, ils ne sont pas employés à l'oral.

Y a-t-il en français des pronoms utilisés de la même façon que dans ces deux langues ? Ou existent-ils mais ne sont plus utilisés dans aucun contexte ?

Comment: Je connais pas d’exemple de ce genre en français mais je suis surpris par "vos" & "vosotros"… qui sont absolument contemporains en espagnol à ce que je sache, autant qu’en français…

vos → vos
vosotros → vous autres

Comment: @Stéphane *Vosotros* est c'est vrai absolument courant en espagnol ibérique mais *Vos* y est un archaïsme qui n'est plus du tout utilisé et qui correspondait exactement au vouvoiement français. Il ne faut donc pas confondre *vos* (vouvoiement singulier utilisé comme nouveau tutoiement) avec *vosotros* (tutoiement pluriel), comme il ne faut pas confondre *vosotros* avec *ustedes* (pluriel de *usted* and Espagne et pluriel de *tù*, *vos* et *usted* en Amérique Latine). La conjugaison moderne au présent est parfois différente: *tú quieres/eres*, *vos querés/sos*, *vosotros queréis/sois*.

Answer (score 8):

***[Icelle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/Icelle)*** et ses dérivés sont assez sympathiques : l'ancêtre de *celle-ci* et ses acolytes peuvent être utilisés de nos jours et seront parfaitement entendus.

Answer (score 3):

Dans beaucoup des dialectes espagnols d'Amérique Latine, le tutoiement à été supplanté par *vos*. De manière plus importante encore, le tutoiement pluriel (*vosotros*) a été remplacé par le générique *ustedes* qui, contrairement à l'espagnol européen mais comme en français, est à la fois le pluriel de *vos*/*tu* et de *usted*.

En brésilien, un changement similaire est apparu où *você* replace le *tu* original.

L'anglais est allé encore plus loin en faisant disparaître son tutoiement (*Thou*) et en généralisant le vouvoiement (You) aujourd'hui utilisé pour toutes les formes possibles de la deuxième personne (singulier et pluriel, tutoiement et vouvoiement).

Il n'y a pas eu de processus similaire ne français où le pronom **tu** continue à être employé (singulier/informel) et où **vous** est utilisé pour toutes les autres formes (pluriel de **tu**, singulier et pluriel de **vous**).

D'une manière générale, tous les pronoms personnels génériques (*je / tu / il / elle / nous / vous / ils / elles / me / te / se / lui / eux / leur / moi / toi / soi / on / en...*) sont toujours utilisés. Seules quelques simplifications orthographiques et grammaticales ont affecté les [pronoms personnels de l'ancien français](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/ancien-francais-pronoms-personnels.php), ex : *je/jou* → je, *le/ele/li* → elle, *nos/nus* → nous, *vos* → vous, *els/eus* → eux, *lor* → leur, etc.

Cependant, une transformation similaire au *tu → vos* affecte le français parlé moderne. Il s'agit de la disparition de **nous** quand il est utilisé comme sujet et son remplacement par **on** dans <s>90%</s> 99% des cas.

Un phénomène curieux accompagne cette évolution. Beaucoup de francophones n'ont pas conscience de sa réalité et sont même souvent persuadés de continuer à utiliser la première personne du pluriel avec le pronom **nous** alors que dans les faits ce n'est pas le cas. Attention, il s'agit uniquement de **nous** quand il est directement le sujet du verbe. Dans les autre cas (par exemple en apposition ou comme attribut), **nous** est toujours présent, ex :

- **Nous**, **on** y va (comparé à « ***Nous***, **nous** y allons » )
- C'est **nous** !

Il existe aussi quatre pronoms personnels argotiques tombés en désuétude mais qui sont souvent encore compris, ce sont [**mézigue**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9zigue), [**tézigue**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/t%C3%A9zigue), [**sézigue**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9zigue) et [**cézigue**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c%C3%A9zigue).

Si on ne se limite pas au pronoms personnels, en dehors de **icelui**/**icelle** déjà évoqués dans la [réponse de cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19919/1109) (voir aussi [cist/cest/cestui](http://ancien-francais.blogspot.fr/2011/11/les-demonstratifs.html) et autres pronoms en usage en ancien français), on peut aussi noter [*maint/mainte*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maint) qui ne sont plus guère utilisés.

Comment: Il existait en ancien français des pronoms personnels qui ne sont plus utilisés de nos jours (des pronoms toniques je crois mais je ne suis pas spécialiste d'anciens français donc je préfère qu'un spécialiste d'ancien français fasse une réponse plus circonstanciée) ou qui ne subsistent peut-être que dans certaines langues régionales. De plus le fait qu'il existait des déclinaisons en ancien français a certainement fait disparaître l'utilisation de certains pronoms personnels.

Comment: Y a-t-il des sources pour le chiffre de 90 % ? Au quotidien, j'entends davantage de « nous » que de on « on ». Je sais que je ne suis pas du tout représentatif de la population, mais ce nombre de 90 % me semble un tantinet exagéré.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Plusieurs études qui arrivent à cet ordre de grandeur. Attention, il s'agit ici de *nous* utilisé comme pronom de la première personne du pluriel. *Nous* continue à être utilisé dans les autres cas, ex: *C'est nous* et *Nous, on y va* alors que *Nous, nous y allons* ne se dit plus beaucoup.

Comment: À l'oral ou à l'écrit?

Comment: @jlliagre Sans vouloir vous embêter, serait-il possible d'obtenir les références de ces études ?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire On est bien plus proche des 99% que des 90%. Voici quelques références: **0,25%** au 19ème siècle **1,06%** entre 1970 et 1995 au Québec, BLONDIEAU Hélène, *The Old Nous and the New Nous: A Comparison of 19th and 20th Century Spoken Quebec French*, 2003  // //
**4,4%,** Picardie, 1982 (39 des 49 nous ont été utilisés par deux locuteurs) : COVENEY Adrian, *Vestiges of nous and the 1st person plural verb in informal spoken French*, 2000

Comment: **0%**, Français de Suisse, **1%** Français de France, fin des années 90s : FONSECA-GREBBER Bonnie & WAUGH Linda, *On the radical difference between the subject personal pronouns in written and spoken European French*, 2003

Comment: **0%**, Paris, 2001-2004 (4 doctorants, 2 bac+2) : BERRIT-HANSEN Anita, *Diaphasic Variation and Change in French Pronouns.On/nous/nous, on in different kinds of spoken French*, 2013

Comment: **5%**, Chat en ligne, 2004 et 2005, VAN COMPERNOLLE Rémi, *Nous versus on : Pronouns with first-person plural reference in synchronous French chat*, 2013

Comment: Et finalement un tableau ici : https://www.erudit.org/revue/arbo/2015/v/n5/1032665ar.html?vue=figtab&origine=integral&imID=im1&formatimg=imPlGr Désolé pour le spam, c'était la seule façon que j'ai trouvé de rendre une telle bibliographie lisible

Comment: Oh, et KING Ruth et al., *The interplay of external factors in grammatical change: First-person plural pronouns in French*, 2011 est une fantastique étude de l'évolution de l'usage (de *je* à *nous* à *on*) des pronons sujets de la 1ère du pluriel en français depuis le XVIème siècle, mais malheureusement pas libre d'accès sur internet

Comment: @Archa j'ai écrit « in spoken French », il s'agit bien d'une évolution du français parlé.

Comment: @Eauquidort Merci pour les multiples références !

Comment: Les utilisations de *maint* et de *maintes* sont plutôt régulières : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maint%2C+maintes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaintes%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @cl-r Non, elles sont en perte de vitesse depuis une soixantaine d'années (attention, il faut regarder le corpus français, pas l'anglais comme dans le lien proposé). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maint%2C+maintes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaint%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaintes%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Je serais bien incapable, hors contexte, de comprendre les -zigues et ne me souviens pas les avoir jamais entendus...

Comment: @LaurentS. Ok, je corrige le tir...

Answer (score 2):

Icelui / icelle indiqués par @cl-r dans sa réponse, seront utilisées aujourd'hui seulement pour donner une fausse coloration médiévale à un texte, pour l'humour [1](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/icelui/186448), un peu comme "thou" en anglais aujourd'hui serait utilisé pour donner un faux aspect "dix commandements".

Les formes pronominales "nous autres", "vous autres" et "eux autres" subsistent de manière régionale, notamment au Québec, pour indiquer le contexte (*Nous autres, nous ne sommes pas comme vous*). Voir [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/difference-between-nous-autres-vous-autres-eux-autres-and-nous-vous). Cela se comprend en dehors du Québec mais n'est pas aussi courant.

Comment: _Nous autres_ s'utilise ailleurs qu'au Québec (je n'y ai pas vécu et il s'utilise peut-être plus là-bas ou dans des contextes où il n'est pas utilisé ailleurs mais ce n'est pas une caractéristique que j'ai détectée chez les Québécois)

Comment: C'est beaucoup plus courant au Québec (v. lien 2 dans ma réponse) mais existe dans d'autres régions aussi, c'est vrai. Ajouté cette nuance dans ma réponse.

Comment: T’es nin d’min coin, ti z’aut’.