# « Vous autre » au singulier ?

Tags: pluriel, locutions, littérature, pronoms-personnels, connotation

On a des locutions de type [ [pronom personnel au pluriel + *autres*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2122) ] (*nous autres, [vous autres](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vous_autres), eux autres*) où des pronoms sont renforcés, servant entre autres à *distinguer clairement* à qui l'on s'adresse ou à *souligner l'opposition*,  avec des nuances à l'[emploi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=nous%20autres&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=3636) (BDL). Au *Bon usage*, on présente des exemples au *singulier* dans la correspondance de Jean-Paul Sartre avec Simone de Beauvoir (ils se sont toujours vouvoyés) :

> Sauf vous autre, mon cher amour, ma petite fleur, [...] je ne compte
>   déjà plus du tout pour le reste du monde. 
>  [...] Vous autre mon
>   petit Castor, vous autre moi. Je vous aime tant.
>
> [ Jean-Paul Sartre, *Lettres au Castor et à quelques autres*, 1940, au LBU §659 ]

---

- > « Le *vous autre moi* (= *vous qui êtes un autre moi*) de la
  >   2<sup>e</sup> citation expliquerait-il tous les *vous autre* de ces
  >   lettres ? »
  >
  > (Grevisse et Goosse, Le bon usage, 14<sup>e</sup>, *ed. Duculot*, §659
  >   h) note R4 in fine)
  >
  > ---
  >
  > Peut-on expliquer pourquoi on serait d'accord ou non avec cette interprétation et si elle serait déterminante dans les exemples, voire généralement pour l'emploi au singulier et sa fonction serait-elle comparable avec ce que l'on retrouve au pluriel ?
- Existe-il d'autres exemples connus d'emploi de *vous autre* au
  singulier et le cas échéant qu'ajoute-t-il à l'emploi avec pronom seul (*vous*) ?
- A-t-on une variante avec le pronom de la deuxième personne du singulier (*tu*...) ; peut-on expliquer ?

Answer (score 1):

"Vous autre" au singulier me semble bizarre et, sans pouvoir l'expliquer, je ne trouve pas d’exemple pertinent de "toi autre".

En plus, l’interprétation donnée pour "Vous autre moi" (= vous qui êtes un autre moi) me semble aussi un peu bizarre, déjà pour "vous autre moi", mais surtout pour les autres exemples sans le "moi".
 (mais même en la trouvant un peu bizarre, c’est quand même une très belle façon de dire "âme sœur", d'après moi)

Je trouve, par contre, pas mal des emplois de "toi" et "vous" avec "autre" (au singulier, sans et avec « d’ ») dans les constructions plus connues comme ["**quel autre que vous/toi**" {*TFLi*, ligne 46} et "**d’autre que vous/toi**" {Idem, lignes 25 et 26}](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autre).
Pas très (du tout ?) pertinent à votre question, d’accord, mais **peut-être** Mr. Sartre et Ms Beauvoir avaient ces constructions plus longues au fond de l’esprit en écrivant "vous autre", tout court, au singulier.

Par exemple :

Peut-être ...

> Sauf vous autre, mon cher amour, ma petite fleur, [...] je ne compte
>   déjà plus du tout pour le reste du monde.

... pourrait se rendre comme :

> Personne d’autre que vous, mon cher amour, … [m’apprécie dans ce/le
>   monde.]

... ou en forme de question comme :

> Quel autre que vous, mon cher amour, … [m’apprécie dans ce/le
>   monde?]

---

Et/ou puis peut-être …

> Vous autre mon petit Castor, vous autre moi. Je vous aime tant.

… pourrait donc se rendre comme :

> [Il n’y a] Personne d’autre que vous mon petit Castor, [il n’y a]
>   personne d’autre que vous [et/pour] moi.   Je vous aime tant

... ou en forme de question comme :

> Quel autre que vous mon petit Castor, qui d’autre que vous [et/pour]
>   moi? Je vous aime tant

Comment: Merci ! C'est pertinent en ce sens que vous y voyez comme une [_ellipse_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(rh%C3%A9torique)), et oui avec l'exemple sans le _moi_ l'explication est plus difficile... est-ce que ça devient pas tout simplement plutôt _vous qui êtes un autre_ tout court. C'est une curiosité dans une note au LBU mais ça pousse un peu la limite de la réflexion sur la syntaxe et est-ce que ça tient, ou seulement dans l'univers de Sartre et Beauvoir... Enfin il y a peut-être un autre pronom qui peut aller avec _autre_, peut-être le possessif dans mon sociolecte, je vais y penser.

Comment: Ahh... j’aime très bien votre idée que peut-être tout ça ne tient que «dans l'univers de Sartre et Beauvoir», presque comme s’ils se parlaient (ou au moins il lui parlait) «en code», où «autre» voulait dire autre chose qu’«autre» entre eux. e.g. Moins dans Exemple 1, mais dans Exemple 2, où il n’y a pas de virgule après les 2 «autre»(s), remplacer «autre» avec  «être=êtes» donnerait peut-être de quoi: «Vous êtes mon petit castor, vous êtes moi.» (Peut-être J-P avait tellement marre d’écrire et d’être associé avec le mot «être» qu’il a trouvé un «autre» mot pour le remplacer de temps en temps!)

Comment: Comme cette construction, "vous autre" au singulier, est vraiment bizarre, et sachant que Sartre a beaucoup réfléchit sur "les autres" (autrui) en philosophie, je penche aussi pour cette interprétation.